# Restrict user to use a specific domain to sign up : django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm a Django newbie.

I'd like to restrict user to use a specific domain (e.g. @gmail.com ) to sign up my Django website, but how to customize the EmailField in my registration form to do that?

FYI, here's my codes.

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label=(u'User Name'))
    email = forms.EmailField(label = (u'Email Adress'))


    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user',)
```

register.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form action = "" method ="post">
{% csrf_token%}
{% if form.errors %}  <p>Please correct the following fields</p> {% endif %}
<div class  ="register_div">
    {% if form.username.errors %}<p class="error">{{ form.username.errors }}</p>{% endif %}
    <p><label for="username"{% if form.username.errors %} class="error"{% endif %}>Username:</label></p>
    <p>{{ form.username }}</p>
</div>
<div class  ="register_div">
    {% if form.email.errors %}<p class = "error">{{ form.email.errors }}</p>{% endif %}
     <p><label for ="email"{% if form.email.errors %} class="error"{% endif %}>Email:<label><p>
    <p>{{ form.email }}</p>
</div>

<p><input type="submit" alt="register" /></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write your own clean functions for the form:

```
class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label=(u'User Name'))
    email = forms.EmailField(label = (u'Email Adress'))

    def clean_email(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if "@gmail.com" not in data:   # any check you need
            raise forms.ValidationError("Must be a gmail address")
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user',)
```

More at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same via HTML5 input tag attribute (pattern). Say for example your domain is foo.com, then the code will be:

```
<input id="email" type="email" pattern="[a-z.]*[@]\bfoo.com" required>
```

Also you can change the error message by using the setCustomValidity of the DOM element.

```
document.getElementById('email').setCustomValidity("Please use an @foo.com email address.");
```