# Django forms EmailValidation not working

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I have been researching on this issue but it seems there's not a lot of explanation around there covering this.

```
...
class RangerRegistrationForm(RegistrationFormUniqueEmail):
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email Address"), validators=[EmailValidator(whitelist=['gmail.com'])])
...
```

Here's the part of my script where I check if the user supplies a gmail account. Unfortunately, as long as it's a valid email it will always pass the check.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict user to use a specific domain to sign up : django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240032/restrict-user-to-use-a-specific-domain-to-sign-up-django)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is NOT a bug in Django (re-read the source code link posted in @catavaran's answer).

A `whitelist` in this case is not a "block everything except for this domain part" solution. Rather, the `whitelist` is a domain part that would otherwise be flagged as invalid by Django's [EmailValidator](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py#L174).

For example, the [default whitelist](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py#L153) is set to `domain_whitelist = ['localhost']`...an otherwise invalid `domain_part` that is being flagged as being OK for this use case.

To validate the domain part of an email field, you are going to need to write your own `clean` function. Something like:

```
class RangerRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email Address"))

    def clean_email(self):
        submitted_data = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if '@gmail.com' not in submitted_data:
            raise forms.ValidationError('You must register using a Gmail address')
        return submitted_data
```

Comment: Oh alright I get it. I'm using it the wrong way then. Wish it was explained better in the docs like the way you did. It was really misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations! You had found a bug in Django.

Look at [this code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py#L174) from the `EmailValidator`:

```
if (domain_part not in self.domain_whitelist and
        not self.validate_domain_part(domain_part)):
    ...
```

If the domain part of the e-mail is valid then checking against the `self.domain_whitelist` just ignored.

Comment: Now that's unfortunate!
Will probably have to use a workaround. Thanks catavaran for pointing that out.

Comment: Has this been reported?

Comment: @rnevius I can't find any ticket for this issue.

Comment: On second glance, is this actually a bug? This functions seems to have nothing to do with blacklisting all except for the whitelist value...it just seems to allow passing a custom domain that would have otherwise been flagged as invalid (i.e. whitelisting an otherwise invalid `domain_part`). If so, I'm not sure this answer is correct.

Comment: I don't know but there doesn't seem to be any line in the script that deals with whitelists aside from these two lines. And if you refer to the EmailValidator documentation, you can actually whitelist an invalid domain_part (ex. 'local')

Comment: That's the point of a "whitelist"...To allow any  otherwise invalid domain part. It's not a blacklist.