# How to allow registrations from specific email domains only like 'gmail' in django?

Tags: django

I tried what the docs said in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.EmailValidator) by using `whitelist` but it's not working, here's what I tried:

```
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator

email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, validators=[EmailValidator(whitelist=["gmail", "yahoo", "hotmail"])])
```

I tried registering with gail.com and I registered normally, so how can I fix this

Comment: I think you misunderstand the documentation. The validator validates *all* domains with a dot (so `gmail.com`), etc. the whitelist is only used for hostnames *without* a dot, like localhost.

Comment: so `whitelist` is useless in my goal here?

Comment: I just found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240032/restrict-user-to-use-a-specific-domain-to-sign-up-django thanks

Comment: no, not entirely, you can subclass the `EmailValidator`, and thus make use of `whitelist`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand the documentation. The [documentation on **`whitelist=…`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.EmailValidator.whitelist) says:

> Whitelist of email domains to allow. By default, a regular expression (the `domain_regex` attribute) is used to validate whatever appears after the `@` sign. However, if that string appears in the whitelist, this validation is bypassed. If not provided, the default whitelist is ['localhost']. **Other domains that don't contain a dot won’t pass validation**, so you’d need to **whitelist them** as necessary.

This thus means that all domains that contain a dot are considered valid, the `whitelist` only will allow some extra domains (like `@localhost`), if you whitelist these.

You can make your own validator by subclassing the `EmailValidator` and alter the [**`.validate_domain_part(…)`** method [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/core/validators.py#L201-L213) however with:

```
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible

@deconstructible
class WhitelistEmailValidator(EmailValidator):

    def validate_domain_part(self, domain_part):
        return False

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, WhitelistEmailValidator) and super().__eq__(other)
```

So then we can make use of the `WhitelistEmailValidator` to do proper validation.

For example:

```
>>> wl = WhitelistEmailValidator(whitelist=['gmail.com'])
>>> wl('test@gmail.com')
>>> wl('info@yahoo.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/python/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/validators.py", line 208, in __call__
    raise ValidationError(self.message, code=self.code)
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['Enter a valid email address.']
```

In your field, you thus add this to the validators:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=60,
        validators=[WhitelistEmailValidator(whitelist=['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'hotmail.com'])]
    )
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but how will I use this? I'm sorry I'm not a pro with django.

Comment: thanks a lot, you are a hero I just saw the example

Comment: looks like newer versions of Django have renamed the 'whitelist' field to 'allowlist'
https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.1.x/django/core/validators.py#L197