# Django email field invalid for international email (in non-english)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using django REST framework.
This is my user model extended from AbstractUser

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
```

I am now trying to check for multiple languages my models can work.

When I validate the user object serializer using  `if user_serializer.is_valid():` it gives me false.

I tried entering the user details by django admin panel but there it says ***Email is invalid***

All other fields like `models.CharField` work perfectly fine with other languages. But this email field does not work.

Answer (score 0):

EmailField is using EmailValidator class by default which might result in an unexpected outcome. You can simply pass a custom validator class that whitelisted the domains you want. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/validators/#emailvalidator) is the default class you might want to extend or overwrite. There is an [answer with more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61854214/2474573) in StackOverflow in case you need more details.